# How can I start and 2d Array from index [1][1] instead of [0][0]

Tags: java

How can i create an array where the first value is not stored at 0 but instead at 1. This is for a theatre seating program where the rows and columns must start at 1 not 0. Please help!I've Been stuck on this for the past 2 days!!

```
int[] [] myarray = new int [2] [3];
```

Comment: You don't. That's how Java works. Internally adjust display values.

Comment: i'd create a class that contains a 2D array of integers and uses indexing starting at 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my best guess at what you want to mimic the orginal array structure in Java using it as a 1 indexed array

```
public class OneIndexed2DArray {
        int[][] indexedArray;

        public OneIndexed2DArray(int row, int col)
        {
            indexedArray = new int[row + 1][col + 1];
        }

        public int GetValue(int row, int col) throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
        {
            if(row == 0 || col == 0)
            {
                throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
            }
            else
                return indexedArray[row][col];
        }

        public void SetValue(int row, int col, int value) throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
        {
            if(row == 0 || col == 0)
            {
                throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
            }
            else
                indexedArray[row][col] = value;
        }
    }
```

Then create it like so

int[] [] myarray = new int [2] [3];

becomes

```
OneIndexed2DArray myarray = new OneIndexed2DArray(2, 3);
```

Set a value at [1][1] = 1

```
myarray.SetValue(1, 1, 1);
```

Get that value

```
int theValue = myarray.GetValue(1,1);
```

Throws an exception if 0 is used as an index to behave as if the 2D array doesn't have 0 index

```
myarray.SetValue(0, 1, 5) returns ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
myarray.GetValue(1, 0) returns ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

You'll have to add more functionality to get things like the size and so on but this should get you started.